# return missing rows by searching by ID in two different dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have the following two dataframes.

current_df:

```
speacial_id  name  count  date
123          al    4       01-01-2020
456          james 4       01-01-2021
789          joe   5       01-02-2021
111          will  2       01-09-2020
222          hal   1       02-10-2009
```

previous_df:

```
speacial_id  name  count   date        alert
123          al    4       01-01-2020  True
456          james 4       01-01-2021  False
789          joe   5       01-02-2021  True
```

I want to find the difference only if `special_id` doesn't exist between the two data frames and merge the values onto previous_df with the output as:

```
speacial_id  name  count   date        alert
123          al    4       01-01-2020  True
456          james 4       01-01-2021  False
789          joe   5       01-02-2021  True
111          will  1       01-09-2020  NaN
222          hal   2       02-10-2009  NaN
```

Please take note of the alert column and the NaN values added.

What I've tried:

```
new_df = current_df[~current_df.isin(
    previous_df.to_dict('list')).all(1)].copy()
```

unfortunately, this is picking up when there is a difference in any of the column, I only want to notice the changes if there are missing special_ids between the two data frames.

Any advices is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like `merge`.

Comment: care to provide more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im pretty sure [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) is what you need:

```
current_df.merge(previous_df, how = "outer")
```

Comment: I was going down this path, but this adds duplicates from the previous_df, I'm just dropping those duplicates now but I didn't know if there is a more elegant way to do this

Comment: @Aldo as can't see your data it is hard to know what is going on, but please check the documentation, I added the link in my answer

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This works for now.